# ODATA Silverlight, and clientaccesspolicy

Tags: c#, silverlight

Just got back from TechEd, and I'm playing around with OData.  I'm using StackOverflow's OData service as my test case.

And I think I'm stopped dead.  I get a security exception, and I believe that the issue is that there is no clientaccesspolicy.xml file on StackOverflow to enable OData for Silverlight.

Am I just completely stuck?  Does StackOverflow not open up a client access policy?

Even more important:

If you want to do data mashups, is Silverlight just not invited to the party?  How would a person consume any given site's OData feed with Silverlight if there was no client access policy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check with [Fiddler](http://www.google.com.ua/search?q=fiddler%20silverlight) the problem. Seems like StackOverflow doesn't open up a client access policy.

> How would a person consume any given
>   site's OData feed with Silverlight if
>   there was no client access policy?

Requests should be done via person's server.